# Access Denied When Adding Loop to Distinguished Name Validation

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to validate the location of some users in PowerShell using the Active Directory account's Distinguished Name.  While trying to find a proper way to iterate through all the sub OUs (designated as `level3s`) I tried implementing a `for` loop to hopefully check each Level 3 for the user.  However once I added the `for` I would get the following as my output.

> Access to the path 'C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\0' is denied.

If I don't concat the current index of the array in the `$expected` string I can properly execute my validation.  An example of that string would be:  `"CN=" + $user.SamAccountName + ",OU=Level3A,OU=Level2,OU=Level1,DC=domain,DC=org"`.  It only seems when I try and loop I have an access issue.

It might also be worth noting that I have elevated permissions so access shouldn't actually be an issue.  Also I'm not running this in an actual PowerShell IDE so I can't "run as admin" if anyone suggests that.

In short my question is;

**Why does adding a `for` loop cause an access denied issue?**

```
$users = @();
$users += Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Level2,OU=Level1,DC=domain,DC=org" -Filter "SamAccountName -like '*lvl'" -ResultSetSize 5000 -Properties $properties | Select $properties;

Function LevelsOUCheck([System.Array]$users, $exceptions = @()){
    $notes = "";
    $invalidUsers = @();
    $level3s= @("Level3A","Level3B","Level3C");

    Foreach($user in $users){
        for($i = 0; $level3s.Length > $i; $i++){
            $expected = "CN=" + $user.SamAccountName + ",OU=" + $level3s[$i] + ",OU=Level2,OU=Level1,DC=domain,DC=org"
            if($user.DistinguishedName -ne $expected){
                if(-Not ($exceptions.Contains($user.SamAccountName))){
                   $invalidUsers += $user.SamAccountName;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if($invalidUsers.Count -gt 0){
        $notes += $invalidUsers.Count + " accounts was in the wrong OU `n";
    }

    return $notes, $invalidUsers
}
```

Per request here's the same function before I added the loop.  And this method doesn't output any errors but I am hardcoding the levels.

```
Function LevelsOUCheck([System.Array]$users, $exceptions = @()){
    $notes = "";
    $invalidUsers = @();
    $level3s= @("Level3A","Level3B","Level3C");

    Foreach($user in $users){
        $expected = "CN=" + $user.SamAccountName + ",OU=Level3A,OU=Level2,OU=Level1,DC=domain,DC=org"
        if($user.DistinguishedName -ne $expected){
            if(-Not ($exceptions.Contains($user.SamAccountName))){
                $invalidUsers += $user.SamAccountName;
            }             
        }
    }
    if($invalidUsers.Count -gt 0){
        $notes += $invalidUsers.Count + " accounts was in the wrong OU `n";
    }

    return $notes, $invalidUsers
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at the `for()` loop:

```
for($i = 0; $level3s.Length > $i; $i++){
    <# loop body here #>
}
```

In PowerShell, `>` is a redirection operator, not a comparison operator.

Every time the loop condition is evaluated, you effectively attempt to write the string `"3"` to a file with the name of `$i` in the current directory, which is why you see the error in question

Replace `$level3s.Length > $i` with `$level3s.Length -gt $i` (`-gt` being the `greater than` operator)

---

If you're new to PowerShell, I'd recommend taking a look at the following help file topics:

- [`about_Operators`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators)
- [`about_Comparison_Operators`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators)

Comment: Ah that's definitely the cause and solution to my issue.  I'm relatively new to PowerShell so clearly I should familiarize myself with the Syntax some more.  Thank you.

Comment: @BlueBarren Happy to help, added some links to relevant topics in the docs